# How to zoom in on (or pop out) particular screen area's

Tags: after-effects, video-editor

I would like to know how to zoom in (or pop out)on a particular boxed screen area (like menu and mouse movements) just like this guy did in this linked video. I wanted to make same thing for my Youtube tutorial series.

Video Link -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the person in the tutorial recorded, cropped and placed each individual element in his video.

You could give "[ZoomIt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/zoomit.aspx)" a try. It's a tool from Microsoft that lets you zoom while recording your screen.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.. Can it be achieved in after effects? Could you please guide me.

Comment: You should check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwd47ezrkXM)  video